# Need help with showing information in a limited space

Tags: popup, modal

Well, it is my first time seeking help for user experience design, so pardon me as I am not accustomed to the proper rules.

I have an information card which shows a thumbnail for a video and below it, information about that video is displayed. The layout is basically like this,

[image]

Well, the difficulty is that the application allows user to add multiple number of fields and value, which means that along with video title and details. The user can add 10 more fields with corresponding values.

I was thinking of using a modal to display additional information about the video, is there any better way as I am not so sure about it.

Comment: Having mixed number of attributes in the cards will make it harder to explore these. As an easy start, you can place all the attributes, including custom, as the filtering options. Show all the attributes in the full card view on the dedicated screen, too.

Answer (score 1):

One of the many resources you can use to solve this problem is a card that has a reveal component, [the way Google's Material Design has it](https://materializecss.com/cards.html#reveal).

Comment: I think this is what I was searching for, thanks for sharing the link